# Wifi icon disappeared from the upper right corner in 20.04

Tags: networking

The Wifi icon disappeared from the upper right corner in ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It seems after an install crashed.
Can you help me diagnosing this issue?
I suppose that something is wrong with network programs (not found).
Thank

Answer (score 0):

I solved entering grub menu, advanced options for ubuntu. Then entering recovery mode and clicking on network. Then resume boot. And OK